# Multilevel and clustering with non nested groups

Tags: stata, nested-models

I work on health data. I want to estimate the probability for a patient to have an intervention. I control hospital effects by random effects and patient residence effects by errors clustering.

I use (Stata 13):

```
melogit y x1 x2 ..., ||hopital:, vce(cluster residence)
```

I have this message:

> highest-level groups are not nested within residence

Theoretically, it is possible to estimate the model? (I think so but I'm not sure.) If it is possible, how can you do it with Stata?

Comment: What is the actual structure of your data? Do you have multiple measures on each patient? Are hospitals nested within residences or residences nested within hospitals?

Comment: I have one measure on each patient. hospitals are not nested within residences and residences are not nested within hospitals. patients from the same residence can go to different hospitals and the same hospital can receive patients from different residences.